# Find pipe character and replace with newline

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I currently have a list of a few thousand elements each separated using the "|" character.  Is there a way with sublime text to place each item on it's own line?

I have attempted to use the Regex find and replace with the parameters of

```
Find: |
Where: doc.txt
Replace: \n
```

For some reason that placed every character on a new line.

For example:

```
listItem1|newItem2|newItem3|newItem4|newItem5|newItem6
```

Had placed each letter on a new line, but I was intending for it to find the character and insert a carriage return.  much like

```
listItem1
newitem2
newItem3
newItem4
newItem5
newItem6
```

Is there a simple way to accomplish this without using a plugin?  I've seen some examples using plugins, but I would think there would be a way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select one `|` and press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> on windows and linux, <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> on mac to select all instances in the file, then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: I knew it was something as simple as that...I'll be using this more often.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @confusedandamused no worries. I'd recommend spending a bit of time learning some of the common [shortcuts](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_win.html). It will save you so much time

Answer (score 4):

To use `\n` in the replace field you need to activate regex.

You need to escape the pipe `|` character to use it in a regex search.

So activate regex find and replace and use these values:

FIND = `\|`

REPLACE = `\n`

That will achieve what you want to do.